# Applet size (15 megabytes) too heavy to load?

Tags: java, swing, audio, applet

I would like to know whether 15 mega is quite heavy applet to load?
My main problem are two sound files(.Au) that its weight is about 9 mega bytes.
Anybody has suggestion of how to use mp3 maybe instead or other ideas of reducing weight?
Thanks

Relevant code:

```
   public class DJ 
    {

        private ArrayList<Clip> m_Records = new ArrayList<Clip>();
        private int m_CurrentRecored = 0;
        private Thread m_MusicThread = null;
        private AppletContext m_AppletContext;
        //java.net.URL m_CodeBase;
        //AppletContext ac;

        public DJ() 
        {
            try 
            {
                createClip(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Music/train.mp3"));
                createClip(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Music/machine.mp3"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(DJ.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

        private void createClip(java.io.InputStream i_SoundFileStream) throws Exception
        {

            InputStream i = new AudioStream(i_SoundFileStream);

            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(i);
            // load the sound into memory (a Clip)
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
            Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            clip.open(sound);
            m_Records.add(clip);
        }
```

Comment: Ooof. .au files are basically uncompressesd raw pcm (8bit/11khz, I think?) Definitely want to switch over to a lossy compressed format. They'll probably turn into 200kb mp3s or something.

Answer (score 5):

> Anybody has suggestion of how to use mp3 maybe instead ..

Add the [mp3plugin.jar](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5B9wDXIGw9lRmpSbEUtenljd1k/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0-miuzcGB8fsXn2EQh3sVolA) of the JMF to the run-time class-path of the applet (in the archive element) and Java Sound will be able to open the MP3s as though they were a wav or au.

The MP3 plugin will not be able to parse some of the more modern MP3s that do non-standard things like including cover art in the MP3, but encode them using a standard MP3 format and it will handle them OK.

---

> ..what did you mean to add the mp3plugin.jar to the run time class path of the applet (in the archive element)?

```
<HTML> 
<BODY> 
<APPLET 
    archive="MyGame.jar,mp3plugin.jar" 
    code="GUI.JPanelGameApplet" 
    width=800 
    height=580>
</APPLET> 
</P> 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

Note that I also changed `Archive` to `archive` (just to keep things consistent) and

```
code="GUI/JPanelGameApplet.class"
```

(generally tolerated, but not correct) to

```
code="GUI.JPanelGameApplet"
```

(which presumes the applet is in the `GUI` package).  If the applet is **not** in the GUI package, the element should be written differently.

---

> I've downloaded the MP3 plugin in the exe format ..

Ignore the EXE link and download the Zip!

> ..I installed it"

Don't bother to run/install the EXE (an EXE is no use to end users on Mac. or Unix/Linux). Just expand the Zip and add the Jar to the run-time class-path

> I'll definitely do that code changes in the HTML..

That will be 'problem solved' (for the embedded applet).

Comment: Okay, but can you please tell me more about what did you mean to add the mp3plugin.jar to the run time class path of the applet(in the archive element?) this is my current HTML:
<HTML>


<BODY>

<APPLET Archive="MyGame.jar" code="GUI/JPanelGameApplet.class" width=800 height=580></APPLET>
</P>

</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: @AndrewThomson:  Another question
I've downloaded the MP3 plugin in the exe format so I will be able to play the sound on my netbeans before.
now I get:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface Clip supporting format MPEG1L3 44100.0 Hz, unknown bits per sample, stereo, unknown frame size, unknown frame rate,  is supported.
        at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:459)
Why is it happening thanks

Comment: @AndrewThomson: Thanks the link is http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/javamp3/1.0-fcs/javamp3-1_0.exe
As I said, I installed it and still getting the exception I mentioned above.I'll definitely do that code changes in the HTML, however when I run my applet in my Netbeans for debug proposes it's not working yet, as explained above.

Comment: *"link is ...exe"* Ignore the EXE link and download the Zip! *"As I said, I installed it"* Don't bother to run/install the EXE (an EXE is no use to end users on Mac. or Unix/Linux).  Just expand the Zip and add the Jar to the run-time class-path *"I'll definitely do that code changes in the HTML"* That will be 'problem solved! *"however when I run my applet in my Netbeans for debug proposes it's not working yet, as explained above."* Same difference.  Add the Jar to the run-time class-path in Netbeans.  How you do that in Netbeans is a separate question that I cannot answer.  I don't use it.

Comment: @andrewThomson:
one exception for what your wrote- writing :code="GUI.JPanelGameApplet" 
don't work - it doesn't find the applet that way.
only code="GUI/JPanelGameApplet.class" works..

Comment: What is the applet name and package name?

Comment: applet name is: JpanelGameApplet   
package: Gui

Comment: I dont get it,what I wrote is just like you see in your edits above,I didn't changed anything! Your edits above about (HTML) are originally what I wrote so don't try to capture me on case sensitive subjects. as a human and not robot I expect you to understand about what I'm talking about for god sake.
Moreover all this useless things has nothing to do with what I wrote to you: (again and hopefully will be understood CORRECTELY):
Your refactoring of my line to: code="GUI.JPanelGameApplet" DONT WORK. 
While leaving that line as I originally wrote:
code="GUI/JPanelGameApplet.class" - IS WORKING.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) for using mp3's.

One option to lower your applet size is load the audio separately or stream it, that way you can at least have a loading bar/image while it's getting the music.

Comment: *"load the audio separately"*  That makes good sense.  Few audio/video formats are well served by being put in a Zip/Jar.  The further compression it offers for such formats is generally no more than 5%.

Answer (score 1):

Check out any [download time calculator](http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/calculate/downloadcalculator.php) — it's more than a minute on a very good line. Sounds like extremely heavy.